# Почему на ПК мигает и со временем выбивает GUI Kivy?

Tags: python, gui, kivy

Есть такой код:
main:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

import Variables
import streams


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kw)
        colorbg1 = [0.145, 0.592, 0.933, 1]
        colorbg2 = [0.11, 0.894, 0.894, 1]
        colorbg3 = [0.965, 0.02, 0.337, 1]

        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.update1(), 1)
        self.button1 = Button(text='Server', size_hint=(1.5, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button2 = Button(text='Status', size_hint=(0.2, 1), background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button3 = Button(text='Connect', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button4 = Button(text='Reconnect', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button5 = Button(text='Internet', size_hint=(0.4, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button6 = Button(text='Status', background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button7 = Button(text='')
        self.button8 = Button(text='')
        self.button9 = Button(text='Control', size_hint=(0.4, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button10 = Button(text='Status', size_hint=(0.2, 1), background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button11 = Button(text='Remote', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button12 = Button(text='Auto', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button13 = Button(text='Power', size_hint=(0.4, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button14 = Button(text='Status', background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button15 = Button(text='')
        self.button16 = Button(text='')
        self.button17 = Button(text='Tank state', size_hint=(1.5, 1), background_color=colorbg1)
        self.button18 = Button(text='Status', size_hint=(0.2, 1), background_color=colorbg2)
        self.button19 = Button(text='', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button20 = Button(text='', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button21 = Button(text='Pump state', size_hint=(0.4, 1), background_color=colorbg1)
        self.button22 = Button(text='Status', background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button23 = Button(text='On')
        self.button24 = Button(text='Off')
        self.button25 = Button(text='Light sensor', size_hint=(1.5, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button26 = Button(text='Status', size_hint=(0.2, 1), background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button27 = Button(text='', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button28 = Button(text='', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button29 = Button(text='Sadok Relay', size_hint=(0.4, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button30 = Button(text='Status', background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button31 = Button(text='On')
        self.button32 = Button(text='Off')
        self.button33 = Button(text='Rear Relay', size_hint=(0.4, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button34 = Button(text='Status', background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button35 = Button(text='On')
        self.button36 = Button(text='Off')
        self.button37 = Button(text='4Relay 1', size_hint=(1.5, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button38 = Button(text='Status', size_hint=(0.2, 1), background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button39 = Button(text='On', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button40 = Button(text='Off', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button41 = Button(text='4Relay 2', size_hint=(0.4, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button42 = Button(text='Status', background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button43 = Button(text='On')
        self.button44 = Button(text='Off')
        self.button45 = Button(text='4Relay 3', size_hint=(1.5, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button46 = Button(text='Status', size_hint=(0.2, 1), background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button47 = Button(text='On', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button48 = Button(text='Off', size_hint=(0.2, 1))
        self.button49 = Button(text='4Relay 4', size_hint=(0.4, 1), background_color=(colorbg1))
        self.button50 = Button(text='Status', background_color=(colorbg2))
        self.button51 = Button(text='On')
        self.button52 = Button(text='Off')

        layout = GridLayout(cols=4, rows=13)
        self.add_widget(layout)
        layout.add_widget(self.button1)
        layout.add_widget(self.button2)
        layout.add_widget(self.button3)
        layout.add_widget(self.button4)
        layout.add_widget(self.button5)
        layout.add_widget(self.button6)
        layout.add_widget(self.button7)
        layout.add_widget(self.button8)
        layout.add_widget(self.button9)
        layout.add_widget(self.button10)
        layout.add_widget(self.button11)
        layout.add_widget(self.button12)
        layout.add_widget(self.button13)
        layout.add_widget(self.button14)
        layout.add_widget(self.button15)
        layout.add_widget(self.button16)
        layout.add_widget(self.button17)
        layout.add_widget(self.button18)
        layout.add_widget(self.button19)
        layout.add_widget(self.button20)
        layout.add_widget(self.button21)
        layout.add_widget(self.button22)
        layout.add_widget(self.button23)
        layout.add_widget(self.button24)
        layout.add_widget(self.button25)
        layout.add_widget(self.button26)
        layout.add_widget(self.button27)
        layout.add_widget(self.button28)
        layout.add_widget(self.button29)
        layout.add_widget(self.button30)
        layout.add_widget(self.button31)
        layout.add_widget(self.button32)
        layout.add_widget(self.button33)
        layout.add_widget(self.button34)
        layout.add_widget(self.button35)
        layout.add_widget(self.button36)
        layout.add_widget(self.button37)
        layout.add_widget(self.button38)
        layout.add_widget(self.button39)
        layout.add_widget(self.button40)
        layout.add_widget(self.button41)
        layout.add_widget(self.button42)
        layout.add_widget(self.button43)
        layout.add_widget(self.button44)
        layout.add_widget(self.button45)
        layout.add_widget(self.button46)
        layout.add_widget(self.button47)
        layout.add_widget(self.button48)
        layout.add_widget(self.button49)
        layout.add_widget(self.button50)
        layout.add_widget(self.button51)
        layout.add_widget(self.button52)




        # box.add_widget(Button(text='Two', on_press=lambda x: set_screen('add_food')))


    def update1(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: one(self), 1)

        def one(self):
            self.button2.text = str(Variables.status_code_server_connections)
            self.button6.text = str(Variables.state_internet_connections)
            self.button10.text = str(Variables.change_recive)
            self.button14.text = str('in work')
            self.button18.text = str('in work')
            self.button22.text = str('in work')
            self.button26.text = str(Variables.receive_from_server1)
            self.button30.text = str(Variables.receive_from_server2)
            self.button34.text = str('in work')
            self.button38.text = str(Variables.receive_from_server3)
            self.button42.text = str(Variables.receive_from_server4)
            self.button46.text = str(Variables.receive_from_server5)
            self.button50.text = str(Variables.receive_from_server6)


class app1(App):

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.update_time(), 1)  # Call update time
        # Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.pr(), 1)

        return MenuScreen()

    def update_time(self):
        self.root.seconds_string = time.strftime("%S")  # Update time




if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    th2 = Thread(target=streams.start1, daemon=True)
    th2.start()
    th3 = Thread(target=streams.start2, daemon=True)
    th3.start()
    th4 = Thread(target=streams.check_Server_sensor_conections, daemon=True)
    th4.start()
    th5 = Thread(target=streams.check_req, daemon=True)
    th5.start()

app1().run()
```

Скрипт logics:

```
logics:
import time
import Variables

def start(self, event):
    return

def pumping():
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        Variables.pomp_state = i
        i += 1
        print(str(Variables.pomp_state))

        time.sleep(1.0)
```

Скрипт streams:

```
      import gc
    import threading
    import time
    from time import sleep
    
    import requests
    
    from urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError, NewConnectionError, ResponseError
    
    import Variables
    
    lock = threading.RLock()
    
    
    def start1():
        while True:
            try:
                if Variables.status_code_server_connections == 200:
                    r4_0 = Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay1
                    r4_1 = str(r4_0[0])
                    r4_2 = str(r4_0[1])
                    r4_3 = str(r4_0[2])
                    r4_4 = str(r4_0[3])
                    params = {'params': str(Variables.parsing_ESP1),
                              'params1': str(Variables.Sadok_Light1),
                              'params2_1': r4_1,
                              'params2_2': r4_2,
                              'params2_3': r4_3,
                              'params2_4': r4_4,
                              'control': 'home'}
                    print(params)
                    r = requests.get('http://f0555107.xsph.ru/index_mob.php', params=params, timeout=3.0)
                    Variables.counting_requaest += 1
                    r.encoding = "UTF8"
                    print('start1 = Ok')
                    print(r.text)
                else:
                    print('start1 ' + Variables.time_now + ' Bad response, status_code= ' + str(
                        Variables.status_code_server_connections))
                sleep(20.0)
            except:
                sleep(20.0)
                continue
                pass
        sleep(20.0)
    
    
    def start2():
        while True:
            try:
                if Variables.status_code_server_connections == 200:
                    url = "http://f0555107.xsph.ru/hello.html"
                    r = requests.get(url, timeout=3.00)
                    Variables.counting_requaest += 1
                    r.encoding = "UTF8"
                    if r.status_code == 200:
                        print('start2 = Ok')
                        with open('response_server.html', 'w') as output_file:
                            output_file.write(r.text)
                        with open('response_server.txt', 'w') as output_file:
                            output_file.write(r.text)
                        text_file = open("response_server.html", "r")
                        lines = text_file.read().split(',')
                        print(lines)
                        # print(len(lines))
                        text_file.close()
                        Variables.receive_from_server = lines
                        Variables.receive_from_server1 = lines[0]
                        Variables.receive_from_server2 = lines[1]
                        Variables.receive_from_server3 = lines[2]
                        Variables.receive_from_server4 = lines[3]
                        Variables.receive_from_server5 = lines[4]
                        Variables.receive_from_server6 = lines[5]
                        Variables.receive_from_server7 = lines[6]
                    else:
                        Variables.state_exchange_data = r.status_code
                        # with open('controlling.txt', 'a') as output_file:
                        #   output_file.write(Variables.time_now + str(lines) + '\n')
                else:
                    with open('controlling.log.txt', 'w') as output_file:
                        output_file.write('start2 ' + Variables.time_now + ' Bad_status_code!' + '\n')
                    print('start2 ' + str(Variables.time_now) + ' Bad response, status_code= ' + str(
                        Variables.status_code_server_connections))
    
                sleep(20.0)
            except:
                sleep(20.0)
                continue
                pass
        sleep(20.0)
    
    
    def check_Server_sensor_conections():
        while True:
            try:
                rg = requests.get("http://f0555107.xsph.ru/hello.html")  # резервный ('http://httpbin.org/get')
                Variables.counting_requaest += 1
                print('check server ' + str(rg.status_code))
                if int(rg.status_code) == 200:
                    Variables.state_server_connections = 'Ok'
                else:
                    Variables.state_server_connections = 'Error!'
                Variables.status_code_server_connections = rg.status_code
                rg.close()
                del rg
                sleep(20.0)
            except:
                print('except! Server')
                Variables.state_server_connections = 'Some error!'
                sleep(20.0)
                continue
                pass
    
        sleep(20.0)
    
    
    def check_req():
        while True:
            try:
                r = requests.get('https://google.com/')  # резервный ('http://httpbin.org/get')
                print('check_reg ' + str(r.status_code))
    
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    Variables.state_internet_connections = 'Ok'
                    print('check_reg')
                else:
                    Variables.state_internet_connections = 'Error!'
                    print('check_reg')
                Variables.status_code_check_req = r.status_code
                gc.collect()
                sleep(20.0)
                # root.after(3000, check_req)
            except:
                print('except! Internet')
                Variables.state_internet_connections = 'some error!'
                sleep(20.0)
                continue
                pass
            gc.collect()
        sleep(20.0)

 Иceive_from_server3 = 0
receive_from_server4 = 0
receive_from_server5 = 0
receive_from_server6 = 0
receive_from_server7 = 'home'
parsing_GPIO_4relay1 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
parsing_ESP1 = 0
Sadok_Light1 = 0

 скрипт Variables:

          from datetime import datetime
    
    
    
    state_server_connections = ''
    state_internet_connections = ''
    state_exchange_data = 0
    pomp_state = 2
    status_code_server_connections = 0
    counting_requaest = 0
    time_now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    receive_from_server = []
    receive_from_server1 = 0
    receive_from_server2 = 0
    receive_from_server3 = 0
    receive_from_server4 = 0
    receive_from_server5 = 0
    receive_from_server6 = 0
    receive_from_server7 = 'home'
    parsing_GPIO_4relay1 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    parsing_ESP1 = 0
    Sadok_Light1 = 0
    
    
    def change_res():
        if receive_from_server7 == 'home':
            a = 'Auto'
        elif receive_from_server7 == 'remote':
            a = 'remote'
        else:
            a = 'Ubnormal'
        return a
    
    
    change_recive = change_res()
```

Comment: а на сколько % загружен процессор и память во время работы ?

Comment: 5-10% процессор и память на 60-70%

Comment: Само приложение практически не ест проц: 1-2%. Памяти занимает 65 мегабайт.Во время выполнения загрузка такая: 5-10% процессор и память на 60-70%

Answer (score 2):

#### Скорее всего, проблема с Threading

Данный модуль выполняет функции питона псевдоним-парралельно.

https://hackernoon.com/concurrent-programming-in-python-is-not-what-you-think-it-is-b6439c3f3e6a

Вероятно, отрисовка окна Kivy и работа остального кода с while-ами является тяжёлой задачей для питона, из-за чего возникают проблемы с морганием.

Для оконных приложений лучше использовать более низкоуровневые языки программирования.